# Access swagger path parameters from middleware

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, swagger-tools

How can I retrieve a swagger path parameter from nodejs?

The swagger definition:

```
  /objects/{id}:
    x-swagger-router-controller: object.controller
    get:
      summary: Get object
      operationId: getObject
      consumes:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: id
          type: string
          required: true
```

What I've tried:

```
req.swagger.params['id'].value
req.query.id
```

Is there any dependency I need? My current dependencies are

```
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "express": "^4.12.3",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "swagger-express-mw": "^0.7.0",
    "swagger-tools": "^0.10.4",
    "swagger-ui": "^3.20.5",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.36"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this: `req.swagger.params['id'].value` --> `req.swagger.params.id.value`.

If you're using express framework and express router you can access request parameters by their name. For example this `/objects/{id}:` path parameter can be accessed like: `req.params.id`